# Open devices and printers using python

Tags: python

i want to open devices and printers using python -->
 control panel--> devices and printers--> double click on the printer icon.
i found this for opening internet options os.system('control.exe Inetcpl.cpl'). need similar one for devices and printers

Comment: `os.popen("control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters")` I don't think you'll get any closer with only built-ins.

Comment: What are the libraries needs to be imported for this?

Comment: i actually want to double click on the printer icon in devices and printers(installed printer).

Comment: To use  the command I wrote earlier about, you have to do a `import os`. However, what you're trying to accomplish ("double clock on the printer") is not something that I think can easily be done with the Python standard library. You will have to do your own research to find a package that can issue clicks. Package-recommendations are however Off-Topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
os.system('control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters')
```

Comment: thanks i am able to use your answer but i found one more simple one            
         start_application    control printers    Devices and Printers

Comment: can you please share with me.